# Can a strong electrical field at power frequency (50 or 60 Hz) be dangerous to humans?

Tags: high-voltage, electric-field

Usually, what is dangerous about electricity is the current – voltage is important as it will determine the current through a given impedance, but not "dangerous per se". So far, so clear.

I am however wondering about if there can be an effect of just the electrical field. Is this really not a thing at all? Imagine a human placed in between two plates, with a huge (let's call it 10 MVrms, just for thrills) potential difference, and the plates are as close to the human as possible without touching.
In other words, I could ask: Is there really no system in the human body that is sensitive to electrical fields?

PS: Possible partial answer to self (that I'd like a "yes" from someone else on anyhow): That electrical field does not even penetrate deeply into the human body, as its conductivity is rather large (see penetration depth/skin depth). But what about close to the surface?

Comment: At 10 MV and as close to the human as possible without touching, the air will break down and you will have a flashover, killing your human.

Comment: France's National Institute for Safety Research has written an article about this : https://www.inrs.fr/risques/champs-electromagnetiques/effets-sante.html I think it's possible to translate into other langage by Google

Comment: Large magnetic fields can supposedly upset cell division and do weird things to the brain.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about electrical engineering.

Answer (score 1):

If you regard the human body as a big bag of aqueous salts, then you can see that it's orders of magnitude lower impedance than the free space around it. This means you can regard external AC fields as simply transferring charge to the surface of the body by capacitance, and that charge then moving around in the body by conduction, usually movement of aqueous ions.

There has been a lot of research on what small AC currents can do to the body, you can buy or rent TENS machines that do just that for local anaesthesia or muscle stimulation. Larger currents would have presumably larger effects, all the way up to heating, and causing electrolytic damage. It's doubtful that you could get to the 10s of mA needed across the chest to cause fibrillation, from capacitive induction by mains frequency fields, without flashover or burning occurring at the extremities.

By charging the surface of the body, external fields, whether AC or DC, can also move hairs around by electrostatic forces, there's a body 'system' sensitive to electric fields! Pointy bits of the body (nose, finger tips) that cause a locally high field could even cause corona discharges. I read somewhere (citation needed) that birds tend not to perch on HV lines above 400 kV or so, and the speculation was that they don't like the feeling of corona discharges from their sharp points, or perhaps electrostatic forces on their feathers.